# Invalid Hook Call on ProgessStep Registration page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, radio-button

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import RNPickerSelect from "react-native-picker-select";
import RadioButtonRN from "radio-buttons-react-native";

import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from "react-native-responsive-screen";
import firebase from "firebase";
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";
import { ProgressSteps, ProgressStep } from "react-native-progress-steps";
import { Tab, Tabs } from "native-base";

var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      name: "",
      Ft: "",
      In: "",
      cm: "",
      lbs: "",
      kg: "",
      age: "",
      gender: "",
      activity: "",
    };
    this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this);
  }


  onSignUp() {
    const {
      email,
      password,
      name,
      Ft,
      In,
      cm,
      lbs,
      kg,
      age,
      gender,
      activity,
    } = this.state;
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .set({
            name,
            email,
            Ft,
            In,
            cm,
            lbs,
            kg,
            age,
            gender,
            activity,
          });
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  functionOne() {
    this.onSignUp();
  }

  functionTwo() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
  }

  functionCombined() {
    this.functionOne();
    this.functionTwo();
  }

  render() {


====>  const [selectedGoal, setSelectedGoal] = React.useState(1);

    const goal = [
      {
        label: "Muscle Gain",
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        label: "Fat Loss",
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        label: "Maintaining",
        id: 3,
      },
    ];

    const details = [
      {
        label: "1 pound per week",
      },
      {
        label: "0.5 pounds per week",
      },
      {
        label: "0.25 pounds per week",
      },
    ];

    const pickerStyle = {
      inputIOS: {
        color: "red",
        paddingTop: 13,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingBottom: 12,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "red",
        borderRadius: 3,
      },
      inputAndroid: {
        color: "red",
      },
      placeholderColor: "white",
    };
    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white", alignItems: "center" }}
      >
        <ProgressSteps
          progressBarColor="red"
          activeStepIconBorderColor="red"
          completedProgressBarColor="red"
          completedStepIconColor="red"
          activeLabelColor="red"
        >
          <ProgressStep
            label="Create your Account"
            nextBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
          >
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.inputUsername}
                label="username"
                placeholder="Username"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCompleteType="none"
                autoCorrect="false"
                onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
              />

              <TextInput
                style={styles.inputEmail}
                label="email"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCompleteType="none"
                autoCorrect="false"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
              />

              <TextInput
                style={styles.inputPassword}
                label="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCompleteType="none"
                autoCorrect="false"
                secureTextEntry="true"
                onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
              />

              <Text style={styles.textBreak}>─────────── OR ───────────</Text>

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.btnGoogle}
                onPress={this.signInWithGoogle}
              >
                <Image
                  source={require("./logo/icons8-google-240.png")}
                  style={{ height: 30, width: 30, top: "20%", left: "15%" }}
                />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    textAlign: "center",
                    bottom: "40%",
                    left: "8%",
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "#4EA5FC",
                  }}
                >
                  Sign In With Google
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </ProgressStep>
          <ProgressStep
            label="Stats"
            nextBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
            previousBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
          >
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
              <Tabs
                tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
                style={{ height: hp("90%") }}
              >
                <Tab heading="Imperial" activeTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}>
                  <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <Text style={styles.txtHeight}>Height</Text>
                    <View>
                      <TextInput
                        placeholder="Ft"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        maxLength="1"
                        onChangeText={(Ft) => this.setState({ Ft })}
                        style={styles.heightImperialFt}
                      />
                      <TextInput
                        placeholder="In"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        maxLength="2"
                        onChangeText={(In) => this.setState({ In })}
                        style={styles.heightImperialIn}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.txtWeight}>Weight</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder="lbs"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      maxLength="3"
                      onChangeText={(lbs) => this.setState({ lbs })}
                      style={styles.weigthImperial}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.txtAge}>Age</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder="18"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      maxLength="2"
                      onChangeText={(age) => this.setState({ age })}
                      style={styles.ageImperial}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.txtGender}>Gender</Text>
                    <View style={{ top: hp("10%") }}>
                      <RNPickerSelect
                        style={pickerStyle}
                        placeholder={{
                          label: "Select a gender",
                          value: null,
                        }}
                        onValueChange={(gender) => this.setState({ gender })}
                        items={[
                          { label: "Male", value: "male" },
                          { label: "Female", value: "female" },
                        ]}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.txtActivity}>Activity</Text>
                    <View style={{ top: hp("13%") }}>
                      <RNPickerSelect
                        style={pickerStyle}
                        placeholder={{
                          label: "Select a level of activity",
                          value: null,
                        }}
                        onValueChange={(activity) =>
                          this.setState({ activity })
                        }
                        items={[
                          {
                            label: "Not Active (Workout 1-2 days a week)",
                            value: "not active",
                          },
                          {
                            label: "A Bit Active (Workout 2-3 days a week)",
                            value: "a bit active",
                          },
                          {
                            label: "Active (Workout 3-4 days a week)",
                            value: "active",
                          },
                          {
                            label: "Very Active (Workout 5-7 days a week)",
                            value: "very active",
                          },
                        ]}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </Tab>
                <Tab heading="Metric" activeTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}>
                  <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <Text style={styles.txtHeight}>Height</Text>
                    <View>
                      <TextInput
                        placeholder="Cm"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        maxLength="3"
                        onChangeText={(cm) => this.setState({ cm })}
                        style={styles.heightMetric}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.txtWeightMetric}>Weight</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder="Kg"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      maxLength="3"
                      onChangeText={(kg) => this.setState({ kg })}
                      style={styles.weigthImperial}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.txtAge}>Age</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder="18"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      maxLength="2"
                      onChangeText={(age) => this.setState({ age })}
                      style={styles.ageImperial}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.txtGender}>Gender</Text>
                    <View style={{ top: hp("10%") }}>
                      <RNPickerSelect
                        style={pickerStyle}
                        placeholder={{
                          label: "Select a gender",
                          value: null,
                        }}
                        onValueChange={(gender) => this.setState({ gender })}
                        items={[
                          { label: "Male", value: "male" },
                          { label: "Female", value: "female" },
                        ]}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.txtActivity}>Activity</Text>
                    <View style={{ top: hp("14%") }}>
                      <RNPickerSelect
                        style={pickerStyle}
                        placeholder={{
                          label: "Select a level of activity",
                          value: null,
                        }}
                        onValueChange={(activity) =>
                          this.setState({ activity })
                        }
                        items={[
                          {
                            label: "Not Active (Workout 1-2 days a week)",
                            value: "not active",
                          },
                          {
                            label: "A Bit Active (Workout 2-3 days a week)",
                            value: "a bit active",
                          },
                          {
                            label: "Active (Workout 3-4 days a week)",
                            value: "active",
                          },
                          {
                            label: "Very Active (Workout 5-7 days a week)",
                            value: "very active",
                          },
                        ]}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </Tab>
              </Tabs>
            </View>
          </ProgressStep>
          <ProgressStep
            label="Goals"
            nextBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
            previousBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
          >
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
 ====>        <RadioButtonRN
                boxStyle={{
                  height: hp("6%"),
                  width: wp("80%"),
                }}
                activeColor="white"
                boxActiveBgColor="red"
                textColor="black"
                textStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                data={goal}
                initial={selectedGoal}
                selectedBtn={(e) => setSelectedGoal(e.id)}
              />
            </View>
          </ProgressStep>
          <ProgressStep
            label="Details"
            onSubmit={() => this.functionCombined()}
            nextBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
            previousBtnTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
            finishBtnText="Finish"
          >
            {selectedGoal == 1 ? (
              <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text style={{ color: "red", fontSize: 15, top: hp("5%") }}>
                  How much would you like to gain per week?
                </Text>
                <RadioButtonRN
                  style={{ top: hp("10%") }}
                  boxStyle={{
                    height: hp("6%"),
                    width: wp("80%"),
                  }}
                  activeColor="white"
                  boxActiveBgColor="red"
                  textColor="black"
                  textStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                  data={details}
                  selectedBtn={(e) => console.log(e)}
                />
              </View>
            ) : selectedGoal == 2 ? (
              <View>
                <Text>Ciao</Text>
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View>
                <Text> you made it</Text>
              </View>
====>         )}
          </ProgressStep>
        </ProgressSteps>
        <Text style={styles.txt}>
          Already have an Account?{" "}
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}
              style={styles.txtSignUp}
            >
              {" "}
              Sign In{" "}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
export default Register;
```

Hey everyone, I'm working on a registration progress step to collect different data from the user, Weight, Heigh, etc..., If you scroll down in the last ProgressStep {I inserted arrows next to the line of codes that I have a problem with} I'm trying to let the user decide between Muscle Gain, Fat Loss, and Maintaining with a RadioButton, and based on the choice, it will show a different  with another RadioButton in it, I tried this way, but it gives an Invalid Hook call, how can I make this work?

Comment: You can't use hooks in class based components.

Comment: yes I know that now, I just don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

It's a Class Component. So you can't use `useState`. What you can do it's to add `selectedGoal` to the `this.state` object in the constructor. Then you can update it by calling `this.setState({ selectedGoal: 'yourValue' })`.